# Doctrine query buider with a where clause for a related entity field

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1, doctrine-query

I have two entities: `Image` and `Tags`, with a many-to-many relationship.

`Image` has some fields: `code`, `description`, `author` and `tags` which implements the many-to-many relationship.

`Tag` has just two fields: `name` and `images`.

I'm building a very general search form, with just an input field where you can write any text and then it will be returned any `Image` that has that text in its `code`, `description` or `author` fields, or in any of its tags `name` field.

For the non-relation fields it's easy. I have in my controller (`query` is just de GET parameter used for the search):

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$qb = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Image')->createQueryBuilder('i');

$qb
->where(
      $qb->expr()->like('i.code', $qb->expr()->literal('%'.$request->get('query').'%'))
      )
->orWhere(
      $qb->expr()->like('i.description', $qb->expr()->literal('%'.$request->get('query').'%'))
      )
->orWhere(
      $qb->expr()->like('i.author', $qb->expr()->literal('%'.$request->get('query').'%'))
      );
```

Now, I don't know how to proceed for the each `name` field of the `tags`.

I had tried to use a virtual field in the `Image` entity that returned all the tags as a string, but I can't use it later in the query builder.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT i FROM YourBundle:Image i
LEFT JOIN i.tags t
WHERE i.code LIKE :q OR i.desc LIKE :q OR i.author LIKE :q OR t.name LIKE :q
```

This should work.

With qb:

```
$qb->leftJoin('i.tags', 't')
   ->where($qb->expr()->like('t.name', $qb->expr()->literal('%' . $query . '%')));
```

Comment: +1. Thanks for your answer. That way works. But I would preffer to use the query builder instead of DQL. I think a good ORM should encourage working in an Object Oriented way. I will set your answer as the correct if nobody else proposes an alternative with the query builder.

Comment: I detect a problem with it. Using that way, images without tags are not considered when searching.

Comment: There should be LEFT JOIN then.